# Change input quantity value for variable product based on weight

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like the quantity selector value to dynamically change based on the weight we specify in the variation section for variable products. Referring to the provided image,

[image: screen.png]

when we set the weight of the product to 0.5 kg, the product quantity selector should begin at 0.5. Similarly, if we set the weight to 1 kg, the quantity selector should start from 1. Furthermore, the quantity selector should adjust accordingly for each weight value we define.
**So based on my code when user click on 0.5 (only number less than 1), user can not add product to cart and appeared an message " please select a value that is no less than one."**

[image: variable.jpg]

here is my code:

```
(function($) {
    // Store the initial quantity step
    var initialStep = parseFloat($('input[name="quantity"]').attr('step'));

    // Wait for the variation to be selected
    $(document).on('found_variation', function(event, variation) {
        // Get the selected variation weight
        var variationWeight = parseFloat(variation.weight);

        // Update the default quantity selector value based on the selected variation weight
        $('input[name="quantity"]').val(variationWeight);

        // Update the step value to match the selected variation weight
        $('input[name="quantity"]').attr('step', variationWeight);

        // Trigger a change event on the quantity selector to update the displayed value
        $('input[name="quantity"]').trigger('change');
    });

    // Reset the quantity step to its initial value when a different variation is selected
    $(document).on('reset_data', function() {
        $('input[name="quantity"]').attr('step', initialStep);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the two filters mentioned above to the `functions.php` file of your active theme.

```
// Removes the WooCommerce filter, that is validating the quantity to be an int
remove_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval');

// Add a filter, that validates the quantity to be a float
add_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'floatval');
```

Please incorporate the following updated code.

```
(function($) {
    // Store the initial quantity step
    var initialStep = parseFloat($('input[name="quantity"]').attr('step'));

    // Wait for the variation to be selected
    $(document).on('found_variation', function(event, variation) {
        // Get the selected variation weight
        var variationWeight = parseFloat(variation.weight);

        // Update the default quantity selector value based on the selected variation weight
        $('input[name="quantity"]').val(variationWeight);
        $('input[name="quantity"]').attr('value',variationWeight);
        $('input[name="quantity"]').attr('min',variationWeight);

        // Update the step value to match the selected variation weight
        $('input[name="quantity"]').attr('step', variationWeight);

        // Trigger a change event on the quantity selector to update the displayed value
        $('input[name="quantity"]').trigger('change');
    });

    // Reset the quantity step to its initial value when a different variation is selected
    $(document).on('reset_data', function() {
        $('input[name="quantity"]').attr('step', initialStep);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

[image]

Comment: Hello sir and thank you very much for your help
But based on your code I have two problems.
1. Selector on  Woodmart's mini cart for variable product does not work properly if their weight is set to a number less than 1, the selector will go up by 2 to 2. (In this example, the weight of one of my variable products is 0.5, but when the product is added to the shopping cart, in Woodmart's mini card, when I click on the selector, it does not increase by 0.5 to 0.5, but increases by 2 to 2.)

Comment: 2. The second problem is for the price. In variable products whose weight is less than one, half price of the product will be shown after adding it to the shopping cart.
(In this example, one of my variable products has a weight equal to 0.5 with a price of 7500, and when the product is added to the cart, the price of the cart icon is displayed as 3500.)